# Protractor Cucumber : how can I capture web driverjs errors in cucumber html report

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I was about to use [cucumber-html-report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-report) plugin to generate the html reports for my framework but I noticed that the report doesn't print the errors which I see on the Command line- for example -"an element not found for locator..".Rather it prints the time out errors. How can I capture the actual errors that I see on the Command line.

Any advice??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tee command to save the Command line - output to a file while also seeing it on command line

```
cucumber (+options) | tee -a logFile.txt
```

It's not as pretty as an html report, but it probably gives you the additional information you want for debugging in an extra file.